# Haskell - Strange truncation behavior of `div`

Tags: haskell, division, integer-division

In ghci I get the following:

```
λ> -1 `div` 2
0
```

However:

```
λ> map (`div` 2) [-1]
[-1]
```

The problem arose when I was using a function `divPair`:

```
divPair :: (Int, Int) -> Int -> (Int, Int)
divPair (a, b) n = (a `div` n, b `div` n)

λ> divPair (-1, -2) 2
(-1,-1)
```

which was really a surprise to me as I expected it to produce `(0, -1)`.

What happened here? I suppose I didn't really understand something about `div` in Haskell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because `` -1 `div` 2 `` is actually parsed as `` -(1 `div` 2) `` which equals `-0` or just `0` as `` 1 `div` 2 `` equals 0. You should use `` (-1) `div` 2 ``.

```
Prelude> -(1 `div` 2)
0
Prelude> (-1) `div` 2
-1
```